# Logcat not showing my app logs in Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

After updates, studio not showing any logs when I filter 'Show only selected Application'.
Verbose is selected
I have tried reconnecting the usb cable and after reconnecting it works.[image]

Comment: Now your problem is solved?

Comment: No. I have to disconnect and reconnect the cable each time.

Comment: nop. I dnt have AVD. I replaced the cable but the problem exist.

Comment: You should click on Allow when using cable

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is problem in your cable. Check to see Android Studio logcat works correctly when you use AVD or not.